# Filter ~6mb JSON object in angujarjs, bad idea?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, csv, ionic-framework

I'm doing a barcode scanner. The only data I have from the client is a "products" csv 6mb file.

I could parse the CSV into a JSON object, then retrieve a bar code, and find the respective item along the 6mb in-memory javascript object. Is it a bad idea? How big a file should be, in this case, to impact on performance?

What if I turn this into an Ionic app? Would it be worse?

I know that it would be better to code a little api server to query on, but is it really necessary?

**EDIT**: The file is downloaded once by an angular service, holding the whole file in a variable (until the app is closed). The filtering would be on that in-memory object.

Comment: yes, it is a bad idea. It implies that each visit will download at least 6 MB and JSON is larger in size than CSV. You should use a server-side solution (database, or parsing the raw file as CSV or JSON) which can be used by your client app, like an API.

Comment: The file is downloaded once by an angular service, holding the whole file in a variable (until the app is closed). The filtering would be on that in-memory object.

Comment: If you do it in the browser, look at versioning the `json` data and cache it in localstorage for faster load times.

Comment: 6mb is fine, even on mobile. 10 is where it starts to get questionable on low-power devices...

Comment: how many lines (items) do you have in this 6mb csv file ?

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:  I made the assumption that the code will be used in a SPA or something where it is run repeatedly, as opposed to being run once per page load or something.**

The browser can handle the 6mb no problem -- look at the average size of images these days.

The real issue is how long it will take you to loop through that data looking for something vs how long would it take to convert the data over to something with a faster lookup... there are a *lot* of things that can affect performance at this point.

For instance, JavaScript objects tend to bog down when you get too many keys.  I'm sure each browser is different, but I started running into trouble around 11,000 or so...

So I recommend splitting the barcodes up into separate buckets -- here is some code that puts all the `1`s together and the `2`s, etc.  It really increases performance when dealing with large datasets.

```js
var barcodes = {
  0: {},
  1: {},
  2: {},
  3: {},
  4: {},
  5: {},
  6: {},
  7: {},
  8: {},
  9: {}
};

function addBarcode(barcode, obj) {
  var firstNumber = barcode.charAt(0);
  barcodes[firstNumber][barcode] = obj;
}

function getBarcode(barcode) {
  var firstNumber = barcode.charAt(0);
  return barcodes[firstNumber][barcode];
}


addBarcode("1104", {
  testprop: true
});

var o = getBarcode("1104");
console.log("testProp should be true.  It is ", o.testprop);
```

Comment: Even for a SPA, if it's used by a lot of people, it'll clog the available bandwidth quickly (lots of simultaneous connections) in addition to needing a high data cap (lots of visits per time period) for no good reason nor any real gain.

Comment: @Emileb The OP didn't ask about network hits.  We could stand to know more about his use-case.

Comment: @Emileb Ionic is a framework for making phone apps in JS that run locally, so the network is (probably) irrelevant.

Comment: @rjmunro but OP isn't using ionic (yet). But you're right, if downloaded once with the app and used locally.

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher that's why I only added a comment to the answer (which I upvoted), which may help future readers with rethink about parsing 6 MB of data in a SPA

Comment: The data would be download from local network once when the app is opened.

Comment: This is an easy good improvement. After inspecting the file closely, there are actually 5 possible barcodes for EACH product. I think this would suffice, otherwise I'll check for a most efficent javascript lib or something?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly if possible you should prepare your data before you bring it into your app. Don't read the raw CSV into your app. Create a presorted .json file and possibly another .json to hold pre-indexed data.

Secondly, **I would see what kind of performance I could get with a simple loop**. It might perform well enough for your needs.

If you wanted to try to pre-indexed the data. It might be an object that looks like this, which has found every 10 thousandth UPC and written its value to an object.

```
var preIndex = [
    //{"limit" : at what index is, value: UPC value},
    {"limit" : 0 , value: 00000001234},
    {"limit" : 10000, value: 00009871234},
    {"limit" : 20000, value: 00019938234},
    ....
]
```

Your code will then need to find which limits surround your UPC.

```
 //find value of X where 
 preIndex[x].value < YourUPC <= preIndex[x+1].value

 //now you only need to loop through 10 thousand items maximum
 //to find your item.
 for(var i = preIndex[x].limit; i <= preIndex[x+1].limit; i++){
     ... // if(myData[i].UPC == YourUPC)
 }
```